# why isn't my jquery altering css attributes on button push?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have an file "dashboard.html" that I am trying to manipulate with jQuery.  The contents are such:

```
<div id="dashboard">

  <span id="contracts">
    <div id="make-offer">
    <button onclick="getDetails()">add</button>
    </div>
    <div id="offer-type" style="visibility:hidden">
    <form action="">
      "Offer what for what???"
      <button id="add-good" onclick="addGood()">good</button>
      <button id="add-service" onclick="addService()">service</button>        
    </form>
    </div>
  </span>
</div>
```

I am trying to hide the "make-offer" div upon clicking the button and show the "offer-type".  However, when I run the following js file, the divs do not change their visibility, though my test message is successful.

```
function getDetails(){
    console.log("getting details.");
    $("#make-offer").css("visibility:hidden");
    $("#offer-type").css("visibility:visible");

}
```

Can anyone spot what I'm doing wrong?  thanks.

Comment: finally, a well worded question! so many simple questions these days are so hard to read...

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You're calling `.css()` improperly. Two choices:

```
$("#make-offer").css("visibility", "hidden");
```

or

```
$("#make-offer").css({ visibility: "hidden" });
```

The second way allows you to set more than one property at a time.

When you pass just *one* parameter, you're asking jQuery to give you the current value of that CSS property.

Answer (score 2):

jQuery does things a little differently

```
function getDetails(){
    console.log("getting details.");
    $("#make-offer").css("visibility", "hidden");
    $("#offer-type").css("visibility", "visible");

}
```